# Size Limitation of NSUserDefault?

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, data-persistence

Is there a size limit to NSUserDefaults? What is it?

I'm afraid that such a limit can cause my app to crash.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no size limit to `NSUserDefaults`, aside from the storage capacity of the device itself.

if you are storing a dynamic amount of variables, **for example,** you are recording time stamps every time the user presses a button, **I would recommend implementing an SQL db.**

Comment: Don't forget the internal memory (RAM).

Comment: Right ... @RAMAN RANA:  pay attention to @Radek Pro-Grammer comment as well.