# Image saving using NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size Limitation of NSUserDefault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698816/size-limitation-of-nsuserdefault)

I am saving the images using `NSUserDefaults`. I want to know the maximum number of images i can save using `NSUserDefaults` or in other words how much memory we can use by using `NSUserDefaults`?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are saving a number of images I would recommend saving images out the filesystem rather than saving them to NSUserDefaults (or CoreData for that matter) and then just saving the file name to NSUserDefaults.

This way there is no need to worry about any capacity restraints.

Saving the image:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"example_image.png"];
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString* imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/saved_example_image.png"];
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

Retrieving the image:

```
NSString* imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/saved_example_image.png"];
UIImage* imageFromFileSystem = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Comment: While it might be helpful, it's not the answer for the question being asked.